# page became blank after reloading

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

cant under stand that after reloading the member page (after login) the page became blank. but all other things are working properly.

bellow is the code of login_execution.php page after login form page

```
<?php

session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('loged', $con);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
$password=md5($password); 
 $sql="SELECT username FROM  list WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1)
{
session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    session_write_close();
    echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>username</th>";



     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) 

    ?>
  <tr style="background-color:blue;color:white;"> 
          <td><font size="6"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></font></td>
          <h1 align="center"><font size="6" color="blue">welcome <?php echo $row['username']; ?></font></h1>
          <p align="right"><font size="4" color="#380B61"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></font></td>





        </tr>
          <?php


echo "</table>";
}

else 
{
?> 
<h1 align="center"><font size="4" color="red">enter coerrect username and password</font></h1>
<td><a href="login.php">BACK</a></td>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: just check wether your you have 'submit' in your post data , as well as echo your sql query & run it in your db & check wether it's correct ..

Comment: yaa its working properly but after reloding the page the became blank totaly

Comment: ok.. You have added else for the if($count==1) , just add else part for the if(isset($_POST["submit"])) & echo  something & see .. 



else 
{
?> 
<h1 align="center"><font size="4" color="red">enter coerrect username and password</font></h1>
<td><a href="login.php">BACK</a></td>
<?php
} 
}
else { echo 'post has submit '; }

?>

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is that if the submit is clicked on when you reload the page the submit button is not clicked on so it will not show anyhting.

To correct this use the code below.

```
<?php

session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('loged', $con);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
$password=md5($password); 
 $sql="SELECT username FROM  list WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['username'];
    session_write_close();
}
}


if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>username</th>";





    ?>
  <tr style="background-color:blue;color:white;"> 
          <td><font size="6"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></font></td>
          <h1 align="center"><font size="6" color="blue">welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></font></h1>
          <p align="right"><font size="4" color="#380B61"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></font></td>





        </tr>
          <?php


echo "</table>";
}

else 
{
?> 
<h1 align="center"><font size="4" color="red">enter coerrect username and password</font></h1>
<td><a href="login.php">BACK</a></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will because you are checking the submit button is clicked outbound , else you have to redirect to the login page after refresh

```
<?php

session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('loged', $con);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
$password=md5($password); 
 $sql="SELECT username FROM  list WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1)
{
session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    session_write_close();
    echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>username</th>";



     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) 

    ?>
  <tr style="background-color:blue;color:white;"> 
          <td><font size="6"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></font></td>
          <h1 align="center"><font size="6" color="blue">welcome <?php echo $row['username']; ?></font></h1>
          <p align="right"><font size="4" color="#380B61"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></font></td>





        </tr>
          <?php


echo "</table>";
}

else 
{
?> 
<h1 align="center"><font size="4" color="red">enter coerrect username and password</font></h1>
<td><a href="login.php">BACK</a></td>
<?php
}
}
else {
header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```